# Is it OK to leave a buffered channel with data open when there is no receiver?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

Suppose there are 10 senders and one receiver for a channel. A sender-side function takes some time to return value. The receiver only wants one value (the first value received) from the channel, and the other 9 values are not used. The receiver doesn't need to wait for the rest 9 values. That's why I didn't use [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup).

I used a buffered channel, so there will be 9 data in a buffered channel when the receiver takes only the first one. My questions are:

1. Is it OK to leave a buffered channel with data open when there is no receiver? The following example code is a simplied one but if the program is a daemon, will it be garbage-collected eventually?
2. Are there better ways to handle such situation? I tried to use the cancellation channel but failed. And I'm not sure [`context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) fits for this situation.

Example code:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

    i, err := getRandomInt()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }

    fmt.Println("Waiting goroutines to be finished...")
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
}

func getRandomInt() (int, error) {
    ch := make(chan int, 10)

    // 10 senders
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            defer fmt.Printf("Goroutine #%d finished\n", i)
            fmt.Printf("Goroutine #%d started\n", i)

            data := heavyJob()
            ch <- data
            fmt.Printf("Goroutine #%d sent data %d to ch\n", i, data)
            return
        }(i)
    }

    // 1 receiver
    timeout := time.After(2000 * time.Millisecond)
    for {
        select {
        case value := <-ch:
            // uses only the value received first, the rest are discarded
            return value, nil
        case <-timeout:
            return -1, errors.New("Timeout")
        }
    }
}

// takes 1900~2900ms to finish
func heavyJob() int {
    r := rand.Intn(1000)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(r+1900) * time.Millisecond)
    return r
}
```

[Run on playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rITJmPuoki5)

Comment: 1. Yes and 2. No. Once the buffer gets collected the 9 remaining items in it get collected to so why bother with a more complicated solution if there are no other constraints. BTW. The name of the language is Go. Only Go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the main questions:

1. It is fine to leave a channel, it will be garbage collected.
2. This seems opinion based, but for me, if the only reason you create a buffered channel with 10 spaces is so that the sender goroutines can exit; this feels like it would benefit from a redesign. There are other (maybe better) ways of ensuring that the sender goroutines can close.

Essentially you are creating an *implicit* coupling between the number of workers and the size of the buffered channel. Change one of those two numbers, and something will deadlock / break! (as a side note, buffered channels are usually for the case when the consumer and producers work at the same rate, but one does not have a steady output. It's spiky, the buffer smooths out the peaks and troughs.)

With this in mind, I suggest it would be better to be *explicit* about managing the fact that you do not want all the values.

Here is an updated version of the getRandomInt() function. Note the setup of context cancellations using defer at the top, and the use of the select statement on send.

```
func getRandomInt() (int, error) {
    ctx := context.Background() // creates a fresh, empty context
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    defer cancel() // cancels the context when getRandomInt() returns

    ch := make(chan int)

    // 10 senders
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            defer fmt.Printf("Goroutine #%d finished\n", i)
            fmt.Printf("Goroutine #%d started\n", i)

            data := heavyJob()

            // this select statement wil block until either this goroutine 
            // is the first to send, or the context is cancelled. In which case
            // another routine has already sent and it can discard it's values.
            select { 
            case ch <- data:
                fmt.Printf("Goroutine #%d sent data %d to ch\n", i, data)
            case <-ctx.Done():
                fmt.Printf("Goroutine #%d did not send, context is cancelled, would have sent data %d to ch\n", i, data)
            }
        }(i)
    }

    // 1 receiver
    timeout := time.After(2000 * time.Millisecond)
    select {
    case value := <-ch:
        // uses only the value received first, the rest are discarded
        return value, nil
    case <-timeout:
        return -1, errors.New("Timeout")
    }
}
```

Setting up the context with a cancellation means that the context becomes "Done" once the `cancel()` function is called. This is a way to tell all the sender goroutines not to bother waiting to send.

On sending, the select statement blocks until either the context has been cancelled by the `cancel()` function; or the receiver method reads the first value.

I've also removed the buffering from the channel, as there's no need for it anymore.

Comment: @philipjkim, note also that it is now trivial to pass ctx to heavyJob so they can abort once the first one finishes.